# Merge many planes into one smooth surface?

Tags: mesh

I have many small planes, which I want to merge into one smooth surface. I did some search and found "dissolve" is probably the way to go? Here is my simple .blend file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Join tool.

**Object mode** , select **A**ll.

**Ctrl** + **J** to join all the parts.

**Edit mode**, with all selected. open **Tools panel**.

**Tools tab** > **Remove** > **Remove Doubles**.

**Shading tab** > **Normals** > **Recalculate Normals**.